# regexp everything in between string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string that can look in two different ways:

```
foo=bar (everything after "=" including any other character)
or
foo=bar&bar (everything between "=" and "&")
```

I would like to use a regexp for this particular case, how could I replace the value of `foo`

Comment: I think you should use PHP's query string functions instead like `parse_str()` and `http_build_query()`.

Comment: boltclocks comment should have been an answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Matching `(foo)=([^&]+)` will capture `foo` and the value of the stuff on the corresponding right-hand side of the equals sign.  I'm not sure exactly what you're looking to do with it.